# Determine influence of uncertainty of X on Y

Tags: regression, error, measurement-error, error-propagation

I made a measurement in the lab by measuring `Y ~ X` with the help of a very precise lab measurement device. Unfortunately, I cannot reveal the meaning of it though I guess no one would care anyway.

[image]

The regression is: $ Y = 56 - 0.806 * X $

Now, I want to check if it is possible to replace that very precise but quite expensive lab device. Therefore, I have a bunch of different, other devices which provide uncertainties in `X` such as 2 - 10 %.

To evaluate them I would like to determine the resulting uncertainty of `Y` when using these other devices. How do I do that?

My idea so far is very basic: Use the full scale of X (let's say 80), calculate its uncertainty $ \delta_x $ given by the manufacturer (let's say 2 %) which yields $ \delta_x = 80 X / 100 * 2 = 1.6 X $ and use the regression slope to get the uncertainty of `Y`:

$ \delta_y = 1.6 X * 0.806 Y/X = 1.3 Y $

Does that make sense or is it too simple?

edit: I think (4) in http://math.jacobs-university.de/oliver/teaching/jacobs/fall2015/esm106/handouts/error-propagation.pdf is quite what I thought about?